# Entity Framework (code first) creates two foreign key fields for the same property when using subclasses

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

**Overview**

I'm building a web app (C#, MVC, EF, Azure) that helps people play a computer game (named "DotA") by allowing them to keep notes on how they should play. DotA is a 5v5 team game, and each player controls one of over 100 unique "heroes" that have various abilities and attributes.

In my app, you can make two different types of notes: tips and relationships.

**Tips**

A `Tip` is a tip on how to play the hero effectively.

```
[Table(nameof(Tip))]
public class Tip: UserOwnedEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The "HeroSubject" of a tip is the hero this tip applies to.
    /// </summary>
    public Hero HeroSubject { get; set; }
    public int? HeroSubjectId { get; set; }

    //Tips can be categorized
    public TipType Type { get; set; } = TipType.Counter;

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// As the game changes, tips may go out of date; tracking the
    /// applicable patch assists with this, and users can flag a
    /// specific tip as out of date ("deprecated").
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Patch { get; set; }
    public bool Deprecated { get; set; } = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Where the tip was found, possibly a URL. Can give context to
    /// a tip that isn't very intuitive.
    /// </summary>
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

**UserOwnedEntity**

You'll notice that `Tip` inherits from `UserOwnedEntity`, a simple class that contains shared properties for entities that relate to a given `User`:

```
public abstract class UserOwnedEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**Relationships**

A `Relationship` makes a comparison between two different heroes (e.g. "hero X synergizes with hero Y"). `Relationship`s are a superset of tips; they have a subject (hero X), but they also have an object (hero Y). Here's the code:

```
[Table(nameof(Relationship))]
public class Relationship: Tip
{
    public int? HeroObjectId { get; set; }
    public Hero HeroObject { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I've removed all the extra methods from these classes so it's easier to understand the data relationships.

**Users**

That leaves us with the `User` object which brings it all together:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    //Associated objects
    public virtual List<Hero> Heroes { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Tip> Tips { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
}
```

**Hero**

Edit: Adding `Hero` class for completeness.

```
public class Hero: UserOwnedEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Tip> Tips { get; set; } = new List<Tip>();

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual List<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; } = new List<Relationship>();
}
```

**Entity Framework's SQL Interpretation**

Entity Framework creates a normal/expected `Tip' table, but the`Relationship` table contains the following fields:

- Id
- User_Id
- HeroObjectId

**Problem 1: Multiple User Foreign Keys**

The `Relationship` table should not contain a `User_Id` field; it already has a UserId field in the `Tip` table . As it is, a `Relationship` can be associated with 2 `User` records (once in the `Tip` table and once in the `Relationship` table), which should not be possible. It is always null, so certain queries fail when they use this UserId field instead of the inherited field. Why is this second foreign key being created?

The specific circumstance where the query fails is when accessing `Relationship`s via the `User`, as in:

```
var relationship = db.Users.First().Relationships.FirstOrDefault(r => r. Id == id);
```

**Problem 2: Tips and Relationships Can't be Distinguished**

Other than checking for a matching `Relation.Id`, there's no way to tell if a record in the `Tip` table is actually a `Relationship`.

**Preferred Solution**

What I want is two different tables: one for `Tip`s and one for `Relationship`s. I'm just not sure what combination of attributes need to be added to accomplish that goal.

**Or, Failing That...**

If I could get rid of the extra User_Id field and make it so Tips and Relationships would load *as if* they were in different tables, I would be happy with that. Maybe happier, actually.

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of `Hero` class for completeness. And fluent configuration if any.

Comment: @IvanStoev Sure thing. Done. There isn't any fluent configuration.

Comment: Ok, Just another small clarification - is `private` here `private int? HeroObjectId { get; set; }` a typo? Because EF does not map private properties by convention.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ugh, it sure was. The original version has some logic associated with the getting & setting that I took out for this. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your entity model is identified as eligible for using EF inheritance strategy (with this particular configuration - [Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines)).

> What I want is two different tables: one for `Tips` and one for `Relationships`.

While this is possible by configuring [Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) using fluent API, it will not solve the problem with navigation properties/relationships/FKs.

It's because anytime EF see `ICollection<Tip>`, it will make sure it also includes `Relationships` (because `Relationship` *is a* `Tip`). At the same time, in order to support `ICollection<Relationship>`, it would create another FK. So in your case, `UserId` will be used to map `Relationship` to `User.Tips` and `User_Id` (default name by convention) - `Relationship` to `User.Relationships`. Remember - in EF every collection is mapped to a separate relationship.

So you either have to remove/ignore all `ICollection<Relationship>` properties in addition to configuring TPT inheritance.  Or, get rid of EF inheritance at all. There is no way to do the later with data annotations/fluent API setup, so you need to extract a base *non entity* class similar to `UserOwnedEntity`. Something like this:

```
public abstract class TipEntity : UserOwnedEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The "HeroSubject" of a tip is the hero this tip applies to.
    /// </summary>
    public Hero HeroSubject { get; set; }
    public int? HeroSubjectId { get; set; }

    //Tips can be categorized
    public TipType Type { get; set; } = TipType.Counter;

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// As the game changes, tips may go out of date; tracking the
    /// applicable patch assists with this, and users can flag a
    /// specific tip as out of date ("deprecated").
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Patch { get; set; }
    public bool Deprecated { get; set; } = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Where the tip was found, possibly a URL. Can give context to
    /// a tip that isn't very intuitive.
    /// </summary>
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

[Table(nameof(Tip))]
public class Tip : TipEntity
{
}

[Table(nameof(Relationship))]
public class Relationship : TipEntity
{
    public int? HeroObjectId { get; set; }
    public Hero HeroObject { get; set; }
}
```

Of course this will affect other parts of your application because `Relationship` is no more `Tip`. Instead, both `Tip` and `Relationship` now are `TipEntity`, so the `TipEntity` can server the same purpose as `Tip` in non EF related polymorphic code.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I simply created a `Note` class that both `Tip` and `Relationship` inherit from. And of course 'Tip' no longer has any code at all.  But the output was completely compatible with the temporary version I'd created by simply copying and pasting inherited code; the change didn't even force a drop/re-create of the db. Thank you so much!